# Issues replacing Mac OS X with Windows7 on MacBook Pro?

Tags: windows-7, macbook

If I buy a Macbook Pro, reformat the hard drive, and install Windows 7, what issues should I expect? Will I need to install drivers by hand, and if so, are they on the OSX DVD? Will I be able to right-click (!)?

And should the mood take me, can I reinstall OSX from the DVD?

(Just for background - I can't find **any** other decent 15 inch laptop with a Core i* processor and a high-resolution 16:10 screen :( 16:9 drives me crazy, and 1050 vertical pixels is the minimum I am prepared to use VisualStudio on. I am looking for alternatives for when my trusty T61 packs up, and have no interest in OS X, or having it take up valuable hard drive space.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **BootCamp** is, I'd say, the way to go.

Get your new MacBook Pro with OS X installed and open the Boot Camp assistant - it will re-partition the drive for you (you could make your OS X partition as small as possible) and prompt you to insert the Windows 7 disk and restart. You can then configure it to always startup in Windows unless you press <kbd>alt</kbd> at startup.

The advantage is that everything, including drivers, is handled for you and you can easily get into OS X should you ever want to, disadvantage is you sacrifce a small amount of space on your C:\ drive.

The alternative you suggest, reformatting your drive, will be ***much*** more of a headache - Intel Apple's use [EFI not BIOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Firmware_Interface) and so Windows won't just install on blank Mac hardware without the BootCamp infrastructure there to support it ([See this post](http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/windows-classic-linux-other-os/138950-can-i-format-whole-hard-disk-install-windows-vista.html#post795332)). It's possible to do it that way with a bit of work but MUCH more trouble than it's worth.

---

**Edit:** And you can always reinstall MacOS from disc. Hold down <kbd>C</kbd> while starting up to force it to use the DVD/CD for boot

---

**Edit 2:** All the Windows drivers are on the install DVD, and right click is supported (even in OS X :) ) - either plug a 2/3-button mouse into a USB port, or put two fingers on the track-pad while clicking - works in OS X and Windows on my MacBook Pro

Comment: Cheers, that's what I wanted to know :) Do you have any experience of the reported terrible battery life running windows ('cos the GPU is always running)?

Comment: I tend to mostly work plugged in to the wall so I don't tend to notice battery life I'm afraid.